# Product Incrementally Estimates From Regression

Tags: regression

I have a bunch of Point of Sale (POS) data at store/SKU level for a few years and was wondering if it was conceptually possible to run a regression to obtain sales incrementally estimates for each SKU (and if so, how could I structure this?).

Note that I don’t have customer level transactions that would be used in market basket analysis, I just have store/SKU scanned sale data (units and dollars).

Let me know if anyone has any ideas on how I could tell how much of each SKU’s sales are incremental. Would this just be regressing on total sales and using the coefs for each SKU?